# ActionScript 3 Access Dynamically Added MovieClips that are With-In Other MovieClips

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip

How would I access a MovieClip that I had dynamically added to a parent MovieClip.

So say for example I have a movieclip (mc_a), and within it I created a var like so:

```
var b:DisplayObject = new mc_b();
```

I had manually added mc_a to my stage and gave it the "Instance Name": a.

So my question is how do I access b (which is an instance of mc_b) when it is within a (which, in turn, is an instance of mc_a)?

**Edit:**

I have the following variable referencing a MovieClip located on frame 1 of another MovieClip named "mc_dock":

```
var btn_pause:DisplayObject = new mc_pause();
```

I access the dock on the main timeline under frame 1 using the following line:

```
var dock:mc_dock = new mc_dock();
```

and then I used the following 2 lines to see if I can access btn_pause from the main timeline (both of which don't work [by that I mean they return "null"]):

```
trace(dock.btn_pause);
trace(dock.getChildByName("btn_pause");
```

When running I get a null value for both trace statements and the following error:

> > TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
> >         at mc_dock/frame1()

Answer (score 1):

```
a.getChildByName("instanceNAMEhere")
```

or

just access the variable b

Comment: If so, after creating that "b" movie clip trace its instance name via `trace(b.name)`, most likely you'll get an output in a line of `instance349`. Otherwise yes, declare that "b" variable public, and access via `a.b`.

Comment: @Guitarroka you posted very little code so if this doesn't work than it is just a guessing game now.